# Can't Import any GameObject in a List

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a list where I can add objects in my scene, later on I'm going to loop through them to determine the closest object to my character and make the character perform certain actions. As soon as I created a list, it won't allow me to add any object to my list or reference it and I don't understand why that's happening. Here's a video to further clarify my issue
[List Not working for me](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bwPP1PYsXomVfLHXHqov18bjJEZU2BV-/view?usp=sharing)

my code for further inquiries

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RobberMechanic : MonoBehaviour
{
   public List<GameObject> testing = new List<GameObject>();
    // void Start()
    // {
        
    // }

    // // Update is called once per frame
    // void Update()
    // {
        
    // }
}
```

Note: wanted to clarify that my unity version was on 2020.3.1f and now I've tried upgrading to 2020.3.10f and this issue occurs in both versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are trying to do is not possible as you are dragging a gameobject inside your list from the hierarchy onto a prefab in the assets folder. Dragging and dropping works on gameObjects that are already inside the a scene/hierarchy.

To achieve your goal you must either:

1. **Add your Terrorist prefab in the scene**. Drag your Sphinx object inside it. The Terrorist prefab will then have the appropriate reference of the gameObject and can be used properly.
2. **Turn your Terrorist object into a [scriptable gameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html)** you can then add all sorts of different properties and will be easier to manage. There are tons of videos and documentation on it as well.

Comment: ok so as for the first idea, I'm cloning this prefab into the scene with positions included, so if I drag my actual prefab into the scene and then add the objects I need into the list, can I save that data into the prefab (to be used later) and remove it from my scene as I do not want duplicate characters? or do I have to keep the character in the scene all the time?

Comment: No, you will either have to leave the Terrorist Prefab in the scene at all times or you can make the sphinx gameobject into a prefab by adding it to your assets. Then you can drag and drop it in the list (from the assets folder) and it will work.
Edit: After assigning the gameobject to the list re-make the terrorist prefab by simply dragging it into your assets.. select original prefab and you are all set.

Comment: Amazing that's working perfectly, thank you so much. I just have an additional question but it's not the same as the topic, I'm trying to make the character move on its own and perform actions on his own (i'm not controlling him on play), so I'm using AI > navigation and set up a nav mesh. The problem is if the character has the character  controller function and NavMesh Agent it won't move(added a script to find the closest object to it), if I remove the character or controller or increase the offset value it moves (but results in spam warnings because I must set it near the char's height)

Comment: @Kermit I am happy that I was able to help. As for your second question maybe it would be benefitial to create a new question thread specifically on that matter and maybe include some of your code to make it a bit more clear what you are trying to achieve. Nonetheless, to understand the problem a bit more, do you never directly control the player? If so, why would you need it to have a playerController and not just let it be a navMesh agent?

Comment: I just thought the question was not worth a whole thread because I'm pretty sure just a small suggestion would fix it immediately but sure if things are bigger than what I thought it'd be, I'll create a new thread. I think I got it fixed, I was searching online and turns out the "apply root motion" was what caused the character to be fixed in its place for some reason, I'm so dumb. Again thank you so much appreciate your help I've been at this for a while, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a GameObject from your scene to a list in a Prefab which is not possible, you'll have to drop your prefab into the scene before adding game objects to it or make a Prefab of the object you're trying to add to the list.